# Resizing y axis to visualize all variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, line, scale

I have a `data.table` that contains the variable "age_group" (1-5) and a total amount of 801.921 observations. I want to plot the total count (y axis) each age_group (x axis) in a line graph using ggplot.

Age_group 1 has a total amount of 274.000 observations, whereas age_group 5 has only 7 observations. I am struggling with finding the right y scale.

When using a y scale from 0 to 280.000, age_group 3,4,5 are not visually visible. So my question is, can I only divide age_group 1 and 2? Another thought I had was to resize the y scale according to the range of age_group 3, 4, 5 (0-350) and to only mark age_group 1 and 2 on the top of the graph with a dot, label it with the total amount and connect these dots with a dashed line to the line graph. Can you think of another solution?

My code so far:

```
ggplot(data = df1[type == "WORK"], aes(x = age_group)) +
  geom_line(stat = "bin", binwidth = 0.5, color = "lightblue") +
  labs(x = "age", y = "count") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 274150), breaks = seq(0, 274150, by = 50000)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: It is hard to imagine what the output of your code looks like.
Could you add the output of the following command please `dput(df1[type == "WORK"])`

Comment: Sorry! So type is the variable for the activity and the second variable is age_group. So, I want to investigate all age groups within the characteristic "working people" of the variable activity.

Comment: Your suggestion to re scale for groups 3, 4, and 5 and make note of groups 1 and 2 is a decent idea. I wouldn't recommend your approach for only dividing 2 groups, transforming only some of the variables on a graph can be hard to understand and can even be misleading. You could consider a transformation to all of the variable (log possibly?) or maybe a chart type that capture proportions fairly well (like a pie chart).

Comment: If you only have 5 age groups and you are communicating 1 number per age group, I would suggest using a table rather than a graph.